# How to add a noremap which contains spaces to .vimrc?

Tags: git, vim

I have this line in my `.vimrc` file which creates a shortcut for `git grep` using [vim futigive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin:

```
noremap <Leader>] :Ggrep <cword><cr>:copen<cr>
```

Your help is needed to add another noremap line that will ignore .js and .css files! Here's what I wrote and vim doesn't seem to like it:

```
noremap <Leader>[ :Ggrep <cword> -- './*' ':!*.js' ':!*.css'<cr>:copen<cr>
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? Does this work when you type the right-hand side literally?

Comment: Sorry, not sure because it now works as expected, however I'd mark my question as unstable for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use `<Space>`, but I would rather use something like:

```
function! GitGrep()
    execute "normal! :Grep <cwords -- './*' ':!*.js' ':!*.css'<cr>"
    execute "normal! :copen<cr>"
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>] :call GitGrep()<cr>
```

As I am not a vim-fugitive user I haven't tested this, but you got the idea.